# Limit (Properties)

Tags: limits

I’m a high school student studying limits and calculus.

What I would like to know is:

1. If x approaches a, could we **multiply** a constant (-1, 65, etc.) to get stuff like
   -x approaches -a.
2. If x approaches a, could we “**subtract**” values from the two sides (assuming limits work like algebra) to get stuff like

subtract x: 0 approaches a-x

subtract a: x-a approaches 0

I got a feeling that 0 approaches something is false, but somehow x-a approaches 0 seems right. 
Could you explain why subtracting **one number work while the other doesn’t?**

3. Does a limit exists, that couldn’t be solved algebraically (conjugate, etc.) but can only be found using L’Hospital.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: See [Properties of Limits](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx) as well as [Limit of a function: Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties).